# jsPlumb element dragging not working on android browser

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb, nestjs-query

I'm using community version of jsPlumb for drag and drop of an element, the webpage is working good on desktop but elements are not draggable while using on android browser. I have also tried some previously suggested solutions on the similar issue by including touch functions but didn't worked . So somebody can please suggest me what changes or package should I use in order to make it work on android as well

I tried including touch functions but didn't worked . I want the element to be draggable on android browser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.